# Почему if возвращает false, если оно должно выполняться?

Tags: java

Переменную function типа String мы получаем за счет регулярного выражения. Регулярное выражение сравнивается с HTML страницей. То есть в переменной function хранятся некоторый текст с сайта.
funcEx[0] принимает значение "showMSG". Далее идет сравнение, где я сравниваю funcEx[0] == "showMSG" и оно по непонятным мне причинам возвращает false. Ниже прикрепил картинку с результатом выполнения в консоли. Буду благодарен за помощь.

[image: Console]

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine())
{
//  System.out.println(scanner.nextLine());
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<p>(.+?)<\\/p>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(scanner.nextLine());
//  System.out.println(" " + m.find());
    if(m.find())
    {
        // функция с аргументами
        String function = m.group(1);
        // вывод текста взятого с сайта
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        String [] funcEx = function.split(" ");
        // вывод первого слова текста. Как мы видим
        // на картинке вывелся текст: "showMSG"
        System.out.println(funcEx[0]);

        // и в данный момент условие не выполняется :с Выполняется else
        if(funcEx[0] == "showMSG")
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "CMD", funcEx[1], JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Условие ложно");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вместо == ставить .equals(). Возможно это решит вашу проблему и такой способ более правильный при сравнении строк и объектов.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Помогло? Или проблема осталась?

Comment: Помогло! Очень благодарен

Comment: Только не "попробуйте" и "более правильный", а объекты сравниваются через equals() и все тут. Через == сравниваются ссылки на объекты. Если вы не до конца уверены, что как и почему при первом или втором случае происходит, почитайте ответы к вопросу, которым закрыт данный вопрос, там все очень подробно расписано